# Message chunks getting displayed as separate messages instead of a single message

Tags: javascript

I have a mockdata for testing if the message with delays between its segments (chunks) will get displayed as a single message. This is to test when the server fetches a long message which may get delayed, the chunks of those messages will get fetched and periodically typed like in chatgpt
This is the mock data I used

```
longMessage: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultricies nisl sed massa luctus, nec dignissim eros interdum. Integer ultrices ex non magna vestibulum, id fringilla mauris efficitur. Aliquam auctor odio nec arcu euismod, id finibus elit ullamcorper. Nulla sit amet vestibulum nulla. Mauris accumsan hendrerit urna, eget consectetur nisi posuere vel. Sed auctor felis nec nisl tincidunt, id dictum ipsum cursus. Fusce in commodo nunc, sit amet malesuada libero. Sed rhoncus bibendum ligula eget faucibus. Maecenas eu eros ac orci venenatis rhoncus.\n\nQuisque vestibulum nunc eu arcu fermentum, ut tincidunt leo sollicitudin. Integer ut tortor elementum, dictum velit nec, dictum erat. Sed in vehicula nisl, at laoreet ex. Integer quis nulla quis enim aliquam pellentesque nec vitae dui. Mauris ac tincidunt ex. Nam auctor arcu nec ex tincidunt malesuada. Nullam lacinia nec justo eu dapibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque sit amet mi sit amet felis consectetur aliquet sed quis enim. Sed suscipit, sem non consequat convallis, mi mi dictum felis, nec pellentesque justo mi ac elit.\n\nDonec id consectetur ipsum. Sed accumsan leo velit, non maximus dui lacinia nec. Morbi condimentum magna vel erat fermentum malesuada. Nulla non eros odio. Vestibulum dapibus semper felis, ut consequat ipsum sodales non. Fusce et ipsum fermentum, consectetur leo at, cursus nulla. Phasellus nec metus et mauris pellentesque ultricies nec et magna. Sed eleifend odio quis diam vehicula, vel vehicula metus aliquet.\n\nPraesent vel metus ligula. Fusce ac vestibulum lorem. Morbi venenatis felis ut libero efficitur, nec euismod leo efficitur. Morbi fermentum neque in quam tincidunt, at auctor lacus suscipit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer faucibus ipsum at justo ullamcorper, id faucibus felis scelerisque. Proin non risus ac ante vestibulum volutpat. Ut semper id leo id sagittis. Phasellus et fermentum arcu, at condimentum elit. Nullam ultricies sagittis risus, at interdum nisi luctus non. Cras aliquet, velit id elementum feugiat, orci lorem placerat nulla, nec posuere nisi ex id urna. Donec ornare sapien in rutrum gravida. Nulla facilisi. Nulla pharetra lorem at risus pharetra tincidunt.",
```

mock delays between chunks of messages :

```
const longMessage = this.botResponses.longMessage;
const chunks = longMessage.match(/.{1,100}/g) || []; // Split the long message into chunks of 100 characters each
for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
  const chunk = chunks[i];
  await this.simulateDelay(); // Simulate delay between each chunk
  appendMessage('bot', new Message(chunk));
  console.log(chunk)
}

async function appendMessage() {
  messageSpan.className = 'bot-message-text';
  botContainer.appendChild(messageSpan);
  li.appendChild(botContainer);
  if (message instanceof Message) {
    const content = await message.content;
    if (Array.isArray(content)) {
      // If content is an array of chunks
      for (const chunk of content) {
        messageSpan.textContent += chunk; // Append chunk to message span
        chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight; // Scroll chat to bottom
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // Add delay between chunks if needed
      }
    } else {
      // If content is a single message
      messageSpan.textContent = content; // Set the message span content
    }
  }
}
```

someone help me with the logic I am getting each chunk displayed as a separate message